# Core Data fetch returns records other than/beyond setEntity

Tags: objective-c, core-data

**The use-case:** I want to fetch all objects of a given entity. For whatever reason the fetch does not only return the records of the set entity type (= Person), but also all others as well (= Provider, Work,...):

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc =
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
            inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request
                                               error:&error];
```

... returns ...

[image]

It's not like I haven't used this same code in the past... and even in the same app for a different entity, the code works fine.

**My workaround:** My workaround for now is to set a fake predicate, which checks whether the result is NOT a fake ID. But of course it's not pretty and I'd like to understand why Core Data is being weird.

Comment: That's really strange.  A fetchRequest *can't* fetch different entity types unless they are stored in the same table, and that only happens if the entities share a parent entity.

Comment: If this is the case, using the `includesSubentities` flag on the fetch request might help.

Comment: Thank you Avi, that was the mistake.
Also thanks Tom for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was speculated in the comments, it really seems the only theoretical explanation of this phenomenon is that `Person` is the parent entity of all the other entities.

If in the model inspector, your entities look anything like this:

[image]

then this is the problem.

Perhaps you wanted a **relationship** and have confused that with the parent entity?

Comment: Avi and you were correct with your speculations. There are relationships, but for some there's also parent entity set.

Stupid mistake I should have checked first. Thanks for the help!